# How to implement serialization to a stream for a class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, serialization

Whenever I find myself needing to serialize objects in a C++ program, I fall back  to this kind of pattern:

```
class Serializable {
  public:
    static Serializable *deserialize(istream &is) {
        int id;
        is >> id;
        switch(id) {
          case EXAMPLE_ID:
            return new ExampleClass(is);
          //...
        }
    }

    void serialize(ostream &os) {
        os << getClassID();
        serializeMe(os);
    }

  protected:
    int getClassID()=0;
    void serializeMe(ostream &os)=0;
};
```

The above works pretty well in practice. However, I've heard that this kind of switching over class IDs is evil and an antipattern; what's the standard, OO-way of handling serialization in C++?

Comment: @SergeyK: which recent changes ? I have certainly not heard of any.

Comment: I mean this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10332336/1065190

Comment: @SergeyK.: Ah! I think the comments section on the answer itself are probably the best place to discuss it. In fact, I have already started. It seems quite esoteric to me, especially the idea of merging serialization with automatic getters and setters (it's generally bad to mix different concepts). Also reminds me of a certain QT project... in the end, you have quasi-C++ and you lose portability because you are dependent on the availability of the tool that is supposed to morph it into proper, compilable C++. I am not holding my breath.

Comment: Its good to take the took together with the source and just recompile it on the target platform. Qt indeed has a tool called metaobject compiler that generates metainformation for your C++ project.

Answer (score 29):

Using something like [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), while by no means a standard, is a (for the most part) very well written library that does the grunt work for you.

The last time I had to manually parse a predefined record structure with a clear inheritance tree, I ended up using the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) with registrable classes (i.e. Using a map of key to a (template) creator function rather than a lot of switch functions) to try and avoid the issue you were having.

**EDIT**
A basic C++ implementation of a object factory mentioned in the above paragraph.

```
/**
* A class for creating objects, with the type of object created based on a key
* 
* @param K the key
* @param T the super class that all created classes derive from
*/
template<typename K, typename T>
class Factory { 
private: 
    typedef T *(*CreateObjectFunc)();

    /**
    * A map keys (K) to functions (CreateObjectFunc)
    * When creating a new type, we simply call the function with the required key
    */
    std::map<K, CreateObjectFunc> mObjectCreator;

    /**
    * Pointers to this function are inserted into the map and called when creating objects
    *
    * @param S the type of class to create
    * @return a object with the type of S
    */
    template<typename S> 
    static T* createObject(){ 
        return new S(); 
    }
public:

    /**
    * Registers a class to that it can be created via createObject()
    *
    * @param S the class to register, this must ve a subclass of T
    * @param id the id to associate with the class. This ID must be unique
    */ 
    template<typename S> 
    void registerClass(K id){ 
        if (mObjectCreator.find(id) != mObjectCreator.end()){ 
            //your error handling here
        }
        mObjectCreator.insert( std::make_pair<K,CreateObjectFunc>(id, &createObject<S> ) ); 
    }

    /**
    * Returns true if a given key exists
    *
    * @param id the id to check exists
    * @return true if the id exists
    */
    bool hasClass(K id){
        return mObjectCreator.find(id) != mObjectCreator.end();
    } 

    /**
    * Creates an object based on an id. It will return null if the key doesn't exist
    *
    * @param id the id of the object to create
    * @return the new object or null if the object id doesn't exist
    */
    T* createObject(K id){
        //Don't use hasClass here as doing so would involve two lookups
        typename std::map<K, CreateObjectFunc>::iterator iter = mObjectCreator.find(id); 
        if (iter == mObjectCreator.end()){ 
            return NULL;
        }
        //calls the required createObject() function
        return ((*iter).second)();
    }
};
```

Comment: why does `createObject` returns T* when the return type is `@return a object with the type of S`,  should it be S*? I'm new to CPP I'm trying to understand this

Answer (score 21):

Serialization is a touchy topic in C++...

**Quick question:**

- Serialization: short-lived structure, one encoder/decoder
- Messaging: longer life, encoders / decoders in multiple languages

The 2 are useful, and have their use.

[Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is the most recommended library for serialization usually, though the odd choice of `operator&` which serializes or deserializes depending on the const-ness is really an abuse of operator overloading for me.

For messaging, I would rather suggest [Google Protocol Buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). They offer a clean syntax for describing the message and generate encoders and decoders for a huge variety of languages. There are also one other advantage when performance matters: it allows lazy deserialization (ie only part of the blob at once) by design.

**Moving on**

Now, as for the details of implementation, it really depends on what you wish.

- You need **versioning**, even for regular serialization, you'll probably need backward compatibility with the previous version anyway.
- You may, or may not, need a system of `tag` + `factory`. It's only necessary for polymorphic class. And you will need one `factory` per inheritance tree (`kind`) then... the code can be templatized of course!
- Pointers / References are going to bite you in the ass... they reference a position in memory that changes after deserialization. I usually choose a tangent approach: each object of each `kind` is given an `id`, unique for its `kind`, and so I serialize the `id` rather than a pointer. Some framework handles it as long as you don't have circular dependency and serialize the objects pointed to / referenced first.

Personally, I tried as much as I can to separate the code of serialization / deserialization from the actual code that runs the class. Especially, I try to isolate it in the source files so that changes on this part of the code does not annihilate the binary compatibility.

*On versioning*

I usually try to keep serialization and deserialization of one version close together. It's easier to check that they are truly symmetric. I also try to abstract the versioning handling directly in my serialization framework + a few other things, because DRY should be adhered to :)

*On error-handling*

To ease error-detection, I usually use a pair of 'markers' (special bytes) to separate one object from another. It allows me to immediately throw during deserialization because I can detect a problem of desynchronization of the stream (ie, somewhat ate too much bytes or did not ate sufficiently).

If you want permissive deserialization, ie deserializing the rest of the stream even if something failed before, you'll have to move toward byte-count: each object is preceded by its byte-count and can only eat so much byte (and is expected to eat them all). This approach is nice because it allows for partial deserialization: ie you can save the part of the stream required for an object and only deserialize it if necessary.

Tagging (your class IDs) is useful here, not (only) for dispatching, but simply to check that you are actually deserializing the right type of object. It also allows for pretty error messages.

Here are some error messages / exceptions you may wish:

- `No version X for object TYPE: only Y and Z`
- `Stream is corrupted: here are the next few bytes BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB`
- `TYPE (version X) was not completely deserialized`
- `Trying to deserialize a TYPE1 in TYPE2`

Note that as far as I remember both `Boost.Serialization` and `protobuf` really help for error/version handling.

`protobuf` has some perks too, because of its capacity of nesting messages:

- the byte-count is naturally supported, as well as the versioning
- you can do lazy deserialization (ie, store the message and only deserialize if someone asks for it)

The counterpart is that it's harder to handle polymorphism because of the fixed format of the message. You have to carefully design them for that.

Answer (score 7):

Serialization is unfortunately never going to be completely painless in C++, at least not for the foreseeable future, simply because C++ lacks the critical language feature that makes easy serialization possible in other languages : **[reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science))**.  That is, if you create a class `Foo`, C++ has no mechanism to inspect the class programatically at runtime to determine what member variables it contains.

So therefore, there is no way to create generalized serialization functions.  One way or another, you have to implement a special serialization function for each class. Boost.Serialization is no different, it simply provides you with a convenient framework and a nice set of tools which help you do this.

Comment: The [C++ Middleware Writer](http://webebenezer.net) automates writing the serialization functions.

Comment: Actually, C++ has (some) compile-time reflection available through metatemplate libraries. It can be leveraged with an abuse of preprocessor directive and Boost.Fusion. I would rather not go down that road though :x

Answer (score 6):

The answer by Yacoby can be extended further.

I believe the serialization can be implemented in a way similar to managed languages if one actually implements a reflection system.

For years we've been using the automated approach.

I was one of the implementors of the working C++ postprocessor and the Reflection library: LSDC tool and Linderdaum Engine Core (iObject + RTTI + Linker/Loader). See the source at http://www.linderdaum.com

The class factory abstracts the process of class instantiation.

To initialize specific members, you might add some intrusive RTTI and autogenerate the load/save procedures for them.

Suppose, you have the iObject class at the top of your hierarchy.

```
// Base class with intrusive RTTI
class iObject
{
public:
    iMetaClass* FMetaClass;
};

///The iMetaClass stores the list of properties and provides the Construct() method:

// List of properties
class iMetaClass: public iObject
{
public:
    virtual iObject* Construct() const = 0;
    /// List of all the properties (excluding the ones from base class)
    vector<iProperty*> FProperties;
    /// Support the hierarchy
    iMetaClass* FSuperClass;
    /// Name of the class
    string FName;
};

// The NativeMetaClass<T> template implements the Construct() method.
template <class T> class NativeMetaClass: public iMetaClass
{
public:
    virtual iObject* Construct() const
    {
        iObject* Res = new T();
        Res->FMetaClass = this;
        return Res;
    }
};

// mlNode is the representation of the markup language: xml, json or whatever else.
// The hierarchy might have come from the XML file or JSON or some custom script
class mlNode {
public:
    string FName;
    string FValue;
    vector<mlNode*> FChildren;
};

class iProperty: public iObject {
public:
    /// Load the property from internal tree representation
    virtual void Load( iObject* TheObject, mlNode* Node ) const = 0;
    /// Serialize the property to some internal representation
    virtual mlNode* Save( iObject* TheObject ) const = 0;
};

/// function to save a single field
typedef mlNode* ( *SaveFunction_t )( iObject* Obj );

/// function to load a single field from mlNode
typedef void ( *LoadFunction_t )( mlNode* Node, iObject* Obj );

// The implementation for a scalar/iObject field
// The array-based property requires somewhat different implementation
// Load/Save functions are autogenerated by some tool.
class clFieldProperty : public iProperty {
public:
    clFieldProperty() {}
    virtual ~clFieldProperty() {}

    /// Load single field of an object
    virtual void Load( iObject* TheObject, mlNode* Node ) const {
        FLoadFunction(TheObject, Node);
    }
    /// Save single field of an object
    virtual mlNode* Save( iObject* TheObject, mlNode** Result ) const {
        return FSaveFunction(TheObject);
    }
public:
    // these pointers are set in property registration code
    LoadFunction_t FLoadFunction;
    SaveFunction_t FSaveFunction;
};

// The Loader class stores the list of metaclasses
class Loader: public iObject {
public:
    void RegisterMetaclass(iMetaClass* C) { FClasses[C->FName] = C; }
    iObject* CreateByName(const string& ClassName) { return FClasses[ClassName]->Construct(); }

    /// The implementation is an almost trivial iteration of all the properties
    /// in the metaclass and calling the iProperty's Load/Save methods for each field
    void LoadFromNode(mlNode* Source, iObject** Result);

    /// Create the tree-based representation of the object
    mlNode* Save(iObject* Source);

    map<string, iMetaClass*> FClasses;
};
```

When you define the ConcreteClass derived from iObject, you use some extension and the code generator tool to produce the list of save/load procedures and the registration code for.

Let us see the code for this sample.

Somewhere in the framework we have an empty formal define

```
#define PROPERTY(...)

/// vec3 is a custom type with implementation omitted for brevity
/// ConcreteClass2 is also omitted
class ConcreteClass: public iObject {
public:
    ConcreteClass(): FInt(10), FString("Default") {}

    /// Inform the tool about our properties
    PROPERTY(Name=Int, Type=int,  FieldName=FInt)
    /// We can also provide get/set accessors
    PROPERTY(Name=Int, Type=vec3, Getter=GetPos, Setter=SetPos)
    /// And the other field
    PROPERTY(Name=Str, Type=string, FieldName=FString)
    /// And the embedded object
    PROPERTY(Name=Embedded, Type=ConcreteClass2, FieldName=FEmbedded)

    /// public field
    int FInt;
    /// public field
    string FString;
    /// public embedded object
    ConcreteClass2* FEmbedded;

    /// Getter
    vec3 GetPos() const { return FPos; }
    /// Setter
    void SetPos(const vec3& Pos) { FPos = Pos; }
private:
    vec3 FPos;
};
```

The autogenerated registration code would be:

```
/// Call this to add everything to the linker
void Register_ConcreteClass(Linker* L) {
    iMetaClass* C = new NativeMetaClass<ConcreteClass>();
    C->FName = "ConcreteClass";

    iProperty* P;
    P = new FieldProperty();
    P->FName = "Int";
    P->FLoadFunction = &Load_ConcreteClass_FInt_Field;
    P->FSaveFunction = &Save_ConcreteClass_FInt_Field;
    C->FProperties.push_back(P);
    ... same for FString and GetPos/SetPos

    C->FSuperClass = L->FClasses["iObject"];
    L->RegisterClass(C);
}

// The autogenerated loaders (no error checking for brevity):
void Load_ConcreteClass_FInt_Field(iObject* Dest, mlNode* Val) {
    dynamic_cast<ConcereteClass*>Object->FInt = Str2Int(Val->FValue);
}

mlNode* Save_ConcreteClass_FInt_Field(iObject* Dest, mlNode* Val) {
    mlNode* Res = new mlNode();
    Res->FValue = Int2Str( dynamic_cast<ConcereteClass*>Object->FInt );
    return Res;
}
/// similar code for FString and GetPos/SetPos pair with obvious changes
```

Now, if you have the the JSON-like hierarchical script

```
Object("ConcreteClass") {
    Int 50
    Str 10
    Pos 1.5 2.2 3.3
    Embedded("ConcreteClass2") {
        SomeProp Value
    }
}
```

The Linker object would resolve all the classes and properties in Save/Load methods.

Sorry for the long post, the implementation grows even larger when all the error handling comes in.

Comment: I've seen uglier... but not often. I really don't like having an extra-pass in the compilation process modifying *my* code. I don't mind having *extra* code added (like `protobuf` files), but when the extra pass trashes the file and you end up with a mis-compilation, tracking the error is a nightmare.

Comment: Well, we are working around the lack of tools in the language itself - this cannot be done seamless. There is no source code trashing - the generated metainformation is also added to the new source files. If you do not include them in your project, there's no trashing (and no factories/serialization though). The compilation errors seem tricky (once you miss something in the PROPERTY declaration), but one can get used to them as we all do with template class errors.

Comment: I don't promote this as THE solution. Its speed cannot compare to binary serialization, so it is only suitable for small configs.

Comment: I used to see this style of solution often...back in the early days of C++, especially pre-RTTI and pre-templates and definitely pre-metaprogramming.  Most certainly, I wrote something similar on several occasions.  Ultimately, after several years of experience, I've made the personal conclusion that this tries to take a solution that works well for dynamic languages with built-in reflection capabilities  and casts it in a language that is not.  You're actually creating is a mini dynamic type system...and that's *not* C++.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, but it's a huge burden to carry in a system, and greatly increases the learning curve.  If you're going this far, you might consider doing something like IDL and using the OMG CDR.  Yes, it's a heavy burden as well, but it's at least a standard heavy burden.

Comment: Let's just agree that it is a "Works for me" solution :)  It is a real burden and definitely this is a reimplementation of CLR/JVM-like reflection system. Of course, it has its roots in mid-Nineties :) When things have to be done quick and simple, I do not employ C++ - I stick to C# or Python or whatever suits our needs. However, to reuse existing codebase and bind it to dynamic languages, the automated code postprocessor appears to be useful as well. In any other way, this is the thing of the past.

Comment: Oh, about the "pre-metaprogramming" thing. Suppose we've invented the set of templates to wrap our getters/setters and all the save-load mess. Then, once again, you have to register all this (to add some "markup" to the source code, but this time it is just in native C++). With the generated code it is a breeze. And about the learning curve. Yes, with the dominating number of new-age developers used to garbage collection and managed environments the _implementation_ of C++ reflector is unnecessary. Really, all of this is just a well-tested legacy.

Comment: @James_sheford  Added an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963464/1182653  It might not be exactly what you want and it constrains your data structures, but it definitely removes the need for Boost.serialization

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps I am not clever, but I think that ultimately the same kind of code that you have written gets written, simply because C++ doesn't have the runtime mechanisms to do anything different.  The question is whether it will be written bespoke by a developer, generated via template metaprogramming (which is what I suspect that boost.serialization does), or generated via some external tool like an IDL compiler/code generator.

The question of which of those three mechanisms (and maybe there are other possibilities, too) is something that should be evaluated on a per-project basis.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to say!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the closest thing to a standard way would be [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). I would like to hear were and in what context you heard that thing about the class IDs. In the case of serialization I can really think of no other way (unless of course, you know the type you expect when deserializing). And also, [One size does not fit all](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/big-picture.html#faq-6.16).