# Need recommendation for object serialization library in c++

Tags: c++, c, serialization

I am looking for recommendation for object serialization/deserialization library in c++? Which one are the most advanced and open-sourced?

Can it handle

- Any class that users defined?
- Object hierarchy (parent and child classes)?
- A Tree of objects? Class A has an attribute of Class B which has an attribute of Class C?
- STL containers? Class A has a vector of Class B?
- A cyclic of objects? Class A has a pointer pointing to B which has a pointer to A?

I find boost serialization library. I am not sure what is its limitation from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends what you're looking for.  If you're looking for super-fast speed and rapid development within a library, Boost is awesome.  If you're looking for super-fast speed, a little more customizability and cross-library binary compatibility, then Qt is a great solution (not saying that Boost can't be made to do this, too).  If you're looking for crazy interoperability, then look for a text-based serialization system like JSON ([jsoncpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/)), YAML ([yamlcpp](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/)) or XML (*way* too many), each of which have about 8 billion independent libraries.

Answer (score 3):

[Protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html) is a library developed and used by Google for object serialization that is cross language. It may be a bit different in concept from what you're describing, but it's worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 1):

The Linderdaum Engine Core (iObject, iStaticClass and clLinker objects) provide the custom RTTI for C++.

The idea behind the serialization there is simple: we use an automated source code postprocessor (LSDC) to generate all the save/load code and the registration for all of the metaclassses and properties.
Any object can be serialized to and from the abstract tree-based markup language script. XML and custom JSON-like (we call it XLML) script is supported.

The implementation details are described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10332336/1182653

1. Any class derived from iObject is supported
2. Object hierarchies are supported
3. "Trees" of objects are supported
4. std::vector-like containers (supporting push_back/size semantics) are supported
5. Well, the properties are defined explicitly and the "pointer fixup" can be performed in a custom iObject::EndLoad() method (redefined in user classes)