# Is this the right way to read a file input?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is this the right way to read a line from a file, split it into 2 variables(a text and an answer), and then feed those two variables into a vector of a class I created?

example being if i had a text file with a list of questions and answers, would this be how I read each question and answer being on one line together
"12 How many inches in a foot?"

```
Question_Bank::Question_Bank(){};

Question_Bank::Question_Bank(std::string fileName){
    std::cout<<"Please enter the name of the file containing your questions: ";
    cin>>fileName;
    questionsFile.open(fileName);
    while (questionsFile.fail())
            {
            cout<<"Unable to open the file."<<endl;
            std::cout<<"Please enter the name of the file containing your questions: ";
            cin>>fileName;
            questionsFile.open(fileName);
            }
}

void LoadQuestions(){
    std::string blank;
    std::string text;
    std::string answer;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline (questionsFile, line ) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    ss>>answer>>blank;
    getline(ss, text);
    questions.Question(text, answer).push_back();
    if (questionsFile.eof()){
            break;
            }
    }
questionsFile.close();
}

Question GetNextQuestion(){
    return questions;
}
```

The Question class

```
Question::Question(){};

Question::Question(std::string text, std::string answer){
    this->text = text;
    this->answer = answer;
}

std::string Question::GetText(){
    return text;
}

bool Question::AnswerContainsDigit(char digit){
    if (isdigit digit){
    return true
    }
    else return false;
}

std::string Question::GetAnswerWithPlaceholder(std::vector<char> answH){
string tempAnswer = "___"; //3 underscores
    for (int x=0; x < answH.size(); x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < tempAnswer.size(); y++){
                    if (answer.at(y)== answH.at(x){
                            tempAnswer.at(y) = answH.at(x)
                    }
            }
    }
return tempAnswer;
}

bool Question::AllDigitsGuessed(std::string userGuess){
    if (userGuess == answer)
    return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Examples of the questions and answers are as follows:

```
206 How many bones are in the average adult human?
2000 How many yards are in a nautical mile?
```

Comment: Avoid using `eof` checks.

Comment: Welcome aboard. On this site, we 1) post code, 2) say what it is supposed to do 3) say what it going wrong. I think that your question is probably better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `ss>>answer>>blank;` is wrong in your example `blank` will end up as `"How"`. You need to find a different way to remove any leading blanks. `questions.Question(text, answer).push_back();` looks wrong, you haven't given enough information but I would guess `questions.push_back(Question(text, answer));` And drop the end of file test.

Comment: Does it work? If not what exactly is going wrong? What does the file contain? Can you post a few lines? Are all the answers numbers? Are any of the answers more than one word?

Comment: There isn't really anything wrong with the first approach. You could handle multiple spaces between the number and question with `ss.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ' ');` instead of reading `blank`.

Comment: Do all the questions have answers that are a single number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ writing an object to a file then later reading it in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742361/c-writing-an-object-to-a-file-then-later-reading-it-in)

Comment: ok, i updated my original post with quite a bit more info.  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess instead of

```
questions.Question(text, answer).push_back();
```

you can use

`questions.push_back(Question(text, answer));`

Comment: So each of those two statements are valid?  is either one "preferred" or more acceptable?

Comment: @JohnnyMitchell How is questions declared? Most likly only one of the options will work.