# Can we store an object in a file for later retrieval?

Tags: c++, file, serialization, fstream

I am trying to write a code, where I need to store the intermediate results in a file for later retrieval. For example, I need to store all the values in an 3D Array in a file, with the dimensions and later retrieve the array for later use. Is there a way I could preserve the object for later use, by storing in a file. For Example....

```
class Obj {
};

Obj ***array;
//declare and initialize the 3d Array.
.
.
.
//do some modifications
.
.
.
.
write the object in the file
ofstream file;
file.open("some_file.txt");
file<<array;
.
.
.
end program.

reopen another program
ifstream file;
file.open("some_file.txt");
Obj *another_array;
file>>another_array;
```

Dont look too much details in the code snippet.
its just an example..

Thanks...
I think there is another think called binary serialization...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement serialization in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809670/how-to-implement-serialization-in-c)

Comment: How good is to use Binary serialization??? I use lots of pointers inside....

Comment: Poorly phrased and an exact duplicate of older questions. I recommend searching SO for similar topics, as this has been answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed called serialization. You're best off not reinventing the wheel. Use [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
ofstream file("some_file.bin", ios::binary);
file.write(array, sizeof(array));
file.close();
```