# Understanding ClassLoaders in Java

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I'm fairly new to the JVM and ClassLoaders. I have these two classes:

```
public abstract class CoreModule extends Entity

public final class EventManager extends CoreModule
```

At the start of the program, I create an instance of `EventManager`. So I understand that the JVM knows what `Entity` class is and how to load it (that is, it knows what `ClassLoader` to use), since `EventManager` is a grand-child. But when an `Entity` instance is passed by some serialization mechanism, it throws `ClassNotFoundException`. I have to manually set the `ClassLoader` to use (`Event.class.getClassLoader()`).

How come the JVM does not know what `Event` class is or how to load it if it already did it?

Comment: Can you provide more details about infrastructure?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by "infrastructure". The JVM proper is Dalvik.

Comment: Is it webapplication or desktop application?are you using any frameworks? are you using any special classes for serialization etc.,

Comment: @thinksteep It's hardly a webapplication/desktop application running on an Android phone.

Comment: It's a standard Android service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the JVM does not figure this out "magically". 
It is all based on a system class loader which will vary depending on the environment you use. Then each thread has a context ClassLoader which derives from this automatically.

The context ClassLoader you can change by using [Thread.setContextClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29)

If your serialization code should be able to resolve a class not visible from the context ClassLoader you need to set this the way you did.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now that when de-serialization is done, it's a system thread that does it, and thus, it doesn't know about my class.

Answer (score 1):

Just by creating an instance of `EventManager` you didn't show the JVM how to load it. In fact, you're not talking to the JVM here. You're talking to one specific classloader, and when that same classloader is not in charge at the time of deserialization, you can get an error. That's why your problem is all about what clasloader is in charge at what point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand the class loading mechanism much better now.