# Cannot Convert From type x to type x

Tags: c++

I got a simple class which just wraps a function call to a classes method.
When compiling (Using Visual Studio 2013) I get the error message:

> Error 2   error C2664: 'Sleipnir::Core::Delegate::Delegate(const Sleipnir::Core::Delegate &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (__cdecl *)(void *const ,int &&)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *const ,int &&)' d:\programmieren\delegate\delegate\delegate.h   29  1   Delegate

which is not really helpful.

My code:

```
    template<typename T>
    class Delegate;

    template<typename R, typename... A>
    class Delegate<R(A...)>
    {
        using TFunc = R(*)(void* const, A&&...);

    private:
        Delegate(void* const obj, TFunc stub)
            : _objectPtr(obj),
            _stubPtr(stub){}
    public:
        Delegate(R(*const funcPtr)(A...))
            : Delegate(nullptr, functionStub<R(*)(A...)>)
        {

        }
    private:
        template <R(*funcPtr)(A...)>
        static R functionStub(void* const, A&&... args)
        {
            return funcPtr(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
        }
    private:
        void*   _objectPtr;
        TFunc   _stubPtr;
    };
```

anyone got an idea why this happens, or how to fix it?

Comment: How are you instantiating the template?

Comment: `Delegate<void(int)> del = Delegate<void(int)>(&test);`

where test is a simple function

Comment: I think to pass a pointer to a function you should not preceed it's name with `&`, try without it

Comment: can you show the code that uses the class template?

Comment: `functionStub<R(*)(A...)>` is not right at all. The template takes a function pointer, not a type. Why not pass `funcPtr`  as a parameter?

Comment: if i remove the preceeding `&` it doesn't make any difference

and i dont want to call the function, but pass the `functionStub` function itself to the constructor, so i can call it some time later

Comment: @0x499602D2: +1 for observation, but the constructor argument is a run-time thing, can't be used as template parameter.

Comment: out of interest, are you intending the delegate to point to a member function or a free function? I ask because it stores an object pointer.

Comment: So my plan is to store both: member functions and free functions with the same class, so i can simply just call the delegates `operator(Arg...)` at some point and it executes the stored function. I think im currently not doing completely wrong, but the error message i get by the compiler just doesnt make any sense to me.. it's like cannot convert an apple to an apple...

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I found was that you were referencing `functionStub` as `functionStub<R(*)(A...)>` which was wrong because `functionStub` takes a function pointer, not a type. The logical fix would be to pass in the address of `funcPtr` as `functionStub<funcPtr>`, but that fails as well. I believe this is because function arguments are not constant expressions so passing in the address of `funcPtr` is ill-formed because templates can only instantiate with constant expressions and types.

So I suggested in the comments that you should pass `funcPtr` to the parameter of `functionStub` by changing its signature to the following:

```c++
static R functionStub(R (*funcPtr)(A...), void* const, A... args);
```

The subsequent problem with this is that the function type differs from `TFunc`. You can solve this by `std::bind()`'ing `functionStub` to `funcPtr` first:

```c++
: Delegate(nullptr, std::bind(&functionStub, funcPtr, placeholders::_1))
```

This also requires changing `TFunc` to a `std::function`:

```c++
using TFunc = std::function<R (void* const, A...)>;
```

Now we have gotten rid of the errors, but the bind only placeholds one parameter for the call. `A...` could be any number of parameters so we have to use some mechanism that placeholds for a variadic number of arguments.

You can use the `easy_bind()` method as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024223/how-to-implement-an-easy-bind-that-automagically-inserts-implied-placeholders).

```c++
: Delegate(nullptr, easy_bind(&functionStub, funcPtr))
```

And lastly, `&functionStub` can't be deduced as a `std::function` type by `easy_bind()`'s arguments, so you can use a `make_function()` for that.

```c++
template <class Callable>
std::function<Callable> make_function(Callable* callable)
{
    return { callable };
}

// ...
: Delegate(nullptr, easy_bind(make_function(&functionStub), funcPtr))
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4647d49ae1786851)</kbd>

Comment: that works fine! Im going to post my code in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because of this line:

```
using TFunc = R(*)(void* const, A&&...);
```

The delegate's public constructor is deferring to the private constructor, which is expecting a pointer to a function that takes a void* followed by an int. You are passing a function that takes only an int.

I suspect you're looking to build a delegate that can handle both free functions and functions that take a context parameter (such as a `this` pointer).

`std::function` takes care of all of that stuff for you. Are you able to write your delegate in terms of `std::function<R(A&&...)>` ? If so, you can use `std::bind` to store the object pointer for a member function callback.

Comment: I am passing `static R functionStub(void* const, A&&... args)` which takes a void* and then the Args (in my case int) and not the function itself (thats why im using this wrapper function, where i will add another one which calls a classes member function). the `operator()` will look something like that: `R operator()(A... a) const
   {
    return _stubPtr(_objectPtr, ::std::forward<A>(args)...);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work now, thank to 0x499602D2

Here's the code to my Delegate class:

```
    template <class Callable>
    std::function<Callable> make_function(Callable* callable)
    {
        return{ callable };
    }

    template<typename T>
    class Delegate;

    template<typename R, typename... A>
    class Delegate<R(A...)>
    {
        using TFunc = std::function<R(void* const, A...)>;
    private:
        Delegate(void* obj, TFunc stub)
            : _objectPtr(obj),
            _stubPtr(stub)
        {}
    public:
        Delegate(R(*funcPtr)(A...))
            : Delegate(nullptr, easy_bind(make_function(&functionStub), funcPtr))
        { }

        template <class C>
        Delegate(C* const objectPtr, R(C:: * const methodPtr)(A...))
            : Delegate(objectPtr, easy_bind(make_function(&methodStub<C>), methodPtr))
        { }

        template <class C>
        Delegate(C* const objectPtr, R(C:: * const methodPtr)(A...) const)
            : Delegate(objectPtr, easy_bind(make_function(&constMethodStub<C>), methodPtr))
        { }
    public:
        R operator()(A... args) const
        {
            return _stubPtr(_objectPtr, ::std::forward<A>(args)...);
        }
    private:
        static R functionStub(R(*funcPtr)(A...), void* const, A... args)
        {
            return funcPtr(std::forward<A>(args)...);
        }
        template <class C>
        static R methodStub(R(C::* const methodPtr)(A...), void* const objectPtr, A... args)
        {
            return (static_cast<C*>(objectPtr)->*methodPtr)(std::forward<A>(args)...);
        }
        template <class C>
        static R constMethodStub(R(C::* const methodPtr)(A...) const, void* const objectPtr, A... args)
        {
            return (static_cast<C*>(objectPtr)->*methodPtr)(std::forward<A>(args)...);
        }
    private:
        void*   _objectPtr;
        TFunc   _stubPtr;
```

And how i use it in my main class:

```
    void test(int x)
{
    std::cout << "Test - print: " << x << std::endl;
}

struct Printer
{
    void print(int x){
        std::cout << "Printer - print: " << x << std::endl;
    }

    void print2(int x) const{
        std::cout << "Printer - print2: " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, void* args)
{

    Printer printer;

    Delegate<void(int)> del(&test);
    Delegate<void(int)> del2(&printer, &Printer::print);
    Delegate<void(int)> del3(&printer, &Printer::print2);
    del(1);
    del2(1);
    del3(1);
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly OK to answer your own question. That said, this answer seems a bit lazy to me: Posted the code that does the trick without any explanation. You can do better! :-)

Comment: well, @0x499602D2 explained pretty well what was wrong, and what i had to change, so i didnt think any more explanation was needed. I just wanted to post the code, so if someone else is interested in what the working code looks like, can view it now.