# Generating some sort of subclass / type registry at compile-time?

Tags: c++

I am writing an application (a game) that has several subclasses of a parent class, which all need to be registered in a map so that they can be referred to in files read during runtime.

For example, if I have a `Subclass` class, and my file specifies that it needs an instance of `"Subclass"`, my file-parser will look up the value in this map, which is an `std::function` that initializes an instance of subclass and return it as a parent class pointer.

I currently accomplish this from a `registry.cpp` file, where I must manually enter each new class, like so:

```
void register_all ()
{
    registry["Subclass1"] = [] () { return new Subclass1 (); };
    registry["Subclass2"] = [] () { return new Subclass2 (); };
    // ... etc
}
```

I have noticed that other applications with a similar setup seem to be able to automatically register these subclasses using a macro (e.g. [Valve Software's Source Engine, which uses a DECLARE_CLASS macro in the class's cpp file, with no need for a header file or any other configuration whatsoever](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Authoring_a_Logical_Entity#Declaring_the_class).)

How can I accomplish this sort of zero-configuration "subclass registry" in my own application?

Comment: There isn't really a portable solution other than what effectively amounts to the thing you wrote. The solutions you've seen in the wild usually rely on some particular compiler behaviour that isn't standardized (namely the execution of initializers of unused code).

Comment: You could write a moc compiler

Answer (score 2):

These macros basically declare a file scope variable (that includes the class name in the identifier to make them unique). The constructor of this variable calls a function to register the lambda.

eg. Something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<Parent*()>>  actions;
class RegisterClass
{
    public:
        RegisterClass(std::string const& className, std::function<Parent*()>&& action)
        {
            actions.insert(std::make_pair(className, std::move(action)));
        }
};
#define REGISTERCLASS(Class)              \
    static RegisterClass   tmpMyUniqueName ## Class( # Class,  [](){return new Class;})

                                    //               ^ Single # quotes the identifier
                                    //     ^^ Double ## combines the pre and post identifiers.
```

If You use the above with:

```
class X: public Parent {};
class Y: public Parent {};
REGISTERCLASS(X);
REGISTERCLASS(Y);
```

You will get:

```
class X: public Parent {};
class Y: public Parent {};
static RegisterClass tmpMyUniqueNameX( "X", [](){return new X;});
static RegisterClass tmpMyUniqueNameY( "Y", [](){return new Y;});
```

Answer (score 0):

The backing of your current implementation is basically the approach you want. You have a map of id string to default constructor. This can be templatized to make the syntax nicer (see this excellent answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1809715/571778 )

Once you have that, you can keep a `static` copy of this registration map somewhere, and then write a macro to do the registration. Therein lies the trade off. On a game I'm working on, I instantiate different implementations based on if I'm loading the editor or the normal game engine, so being able to substitute different registrations at runtime is an advantage over static registration for my use case.